# Use one modal bootstrap for multiple button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I get data from json and add data with html to my page, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    idbv: 1
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      var id = value.id;
      var content = value.content;
      $("#test").append('<button id="btn_'+id +'"></button><div id="modal_'+id+'" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> <div class="modal-dialog"> <div class="modal-content"> <span>'+content+'</span> </div> </div> </div>');
      //This is the old way i do, it's so bad
      $("#btn_"+id).click(function(){
        $("#modal_"+id).modal("show");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

How can i open modal bootstrap and send data from json to modal bootstrap with one modal?

Comment: Please share related php and html

Comment: You need to attach an event handler function for click on each buttons (https://api.jquery.com/click/) and in each handler you show the specific modal (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp).

Comment: I edited my question, pls see it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/1aeur58f/779/)**.

Just copy the data you've appended to the test element inside the modal and show it like :

```
$('#myModal .modal-body').html( $('#test').html() );
$('#myModal').modal();
```

**Full code :**

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    idbv: 1
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      var id = value.id
      $("#test").append('<button id="btn_'+id +'"></button>');
    });

    $('#myModal .modal-body').html( $('#test').html() );
    $('#myModal').modal();
  }
});
```

Hoept his helps.

Comment: So, please see again my question, how can i send content to modal?

Comment: Add your HTML code please so we could see which modal you're talking about.

Comment: let me check it